# DocuSign: Sending Template with Custom Fields

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign.eSign library from https://github.com/docusign/docuSign-csharp-client

I've created an EnvelopeDefinition:

```
var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
    {
        CustomFields = new CustomFields()
            {
                TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>()
                    {
                        new TextCustomField()
                            {
                                FieldId = "d9d584f6-0a3a-40df-b94f-407c1a90c87d",
                                Name = "A.LoanNumber",
                                Required = "true",
                                Show = "true",
                                Value = "1234567890",
                            },
                    },
            },
        EmailBlurb = "Don't panic! This is only a template test.",
        EmailSubject = "Template Test...",
        Status = "sent",
        TemplateId = "458407ac-f0a0-44e6-a60b-5126e2d0a8cf",
        TemplateRoles = new List<TemplateRole>()
            {
                new TemplateRole()
                    {
                        AccessCode = "1234",
                        Email = "jjeppson@example.com",
                        Name = "Josh Jeppson",
                        RoleName = "Borrower.1",
                    },
            },
    };
```

But no matter what combination of values I have used for properties of the TextCustomField, the default value for A.LoanNumber, "Loan Number", is output in the resulting document.

The envelope sends correctly but none of the fields (only one shown above) have been inserted/replaced in the document.

Using the specified library, how do I override the default values for the custom fields?

Comment: As far as I understand CustomFields are something that used purely internaly. Don't you, by any chance, want to create a TextTab?

Comment: And if so, do you want to override an existing tab, or create a new one?

Comment: Yeah what's your use case here or what exactly are you trying to do with TextCustomFields?  @netaholic may be right in that you might want to use `textTabs` instead, but need to understand what you are trying to accomplish